How do I find the correct planetary spacing for my red dwarf system?
I have a system with a K6.7V star at 0.585 M☉.
The planetary system has 7 orbits --

A tiny, rocky planet at 0.043 AU with a mass of 0.0465 M⊕.
A tidally locked, habitable, water world planet at 0.34 AU with a mass of 0.788 M⊕.
Another rocky planet at 0.64 AU with a mass of
An asteroid belt at 1.24 AU with a mass of 5.994×10^−4 M⊕.
A major gas giant at 2.44 AU with a mass of 350.985 M⊕.
A minor gas giant at 4.84 AU with a mass of 43.143 M⊕.
And lastly, a small, icy-rocky planet at 9.64 AU with a mass of 0.232 M⊕.

I implemented the spacing factor for this system -- it is the logarithmic spacing between orbits of a solar system. I used our (Earth's) solar system's spacing factor of 0.3, which I don't feel is correct for my system with such a small star.
 Additionally, a lot of these masses are extremely rough, and will change. I would like help deciding on the masses, but that probably needs another question to ask.
 I'd greatly appreciate any feedback -- even on parts that are not entirely related to the question!! I'm new to this.

If you don't specify the masses of each body, there is no way you can find any support. Gravity depends on mass and distance.

The closest planet is too close IMHO and doesn't look like being in orbital resonance with the second one, meaning its orbit is unstable and it's likely to fall to the star. You should refine distances to make your planets have at least some resonance in orbital periods, this would help to ensure your star system is stable enough.

@L.Dutch I added some temporary masses to give an idea of what I'm looking to achieve. The asteroid belt calculation is from this link.

@Vesper I see -- I'm using Artifexian's Worldsmith document to calculate my stuff. After chucking in all my data, I got those numbers for the first 7 orbits (I got to choose the distance of the first orbit and the spacing factor based on an inner limit of 0.0061 AU).

Your star is too small for the class you have indicated K9 stars are more than 0.59 M☉, K6.7 should be about 0.675 M☉, please clarify.

Creation of the solar system
One thought that comes to mind is: If a red dwarf sun was formed, it did not use up so much of the mass of a primordial solar-system accretion-disk as our sun did. So, it might be possible, that planets forming in such a system are bigger (and maybe less dense) compared to those in our solar-system. Meaning, a simple down scaling of our system's distances probably won't cut it, if the sun is so much different. Could be that rocky planets close to the sun cannot exist (either they are farther away, or they are really fast, or they are not made of rock but liquid or gas instead).
On the other hand, you are more or less able to explain any distances you need for your story. You can argue, that the situation at forming of the system were so special that the consequences are as you like. You can make any planet as dense as needed, just "add" more heavy or less heavy matter into the accretion disk. Maybe you even want to have an unstable system for dramaturgical reasons.
A quick check for plausibility is to compute the gravitational force of the sun (maybe assume the universal constant G to be as ours) and the centrifugal force of each planet (speed to revolve once around the star). Those two have to match, in order to guarantee a stable (circular) orbit.

This might get you started: Orbital mechanics.
Probably a simplification to circular orbits is helpful.

Habitable zone distance
Also keep in mind that you might want to have a habitable zone. This has not to be computationally correct, but if your sun is very cold (brown dwarfs usually are), the habitable zone is closer to it, than it would be in our solar system. And the outer planets are maybe not gaseous but frozen.
You mentioned a "tidally locked habitable" planet. I think those a contradictory assumptions. Tidally locked implies some kind of matter exchange between the planet and the sun happend at some point until the tidally locked state was settled. That either means your planet has no atmosphere, or no water, or maybe none of both. Also having one side to the sun at all times could mean high temperatures (vaporizing water) and deep freezing temps on the far side. This can all be alleviated by story elements of course.

I can't really comment on the details in the rest of the system but can give you some notes:

The star, as a K6.7V should be ~0.675 M☉, 0.585 M☉ is down in the brown dwarf range.

Based on the mass rather than the class you've stated, since it's the lower of the two, the inner rock is well within the Roche Limit so it will be torn apart by stellar gravity. If you're going with the class in the question this will be doubly true.

The orbit of the proposed water world is habitable for the smaller (mass based) star but based on the K6.7V proposed it is too close and will cook.


